# NPM preinstall script

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg, npm-scripts

I am trying to run some policing script before any packages are installed. 
For Example:

```
{
  "name": "pre-hook-check",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "preinstall": "echo preinstall",
    "postinstall": "echo postinstall"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "abc": "^0.6.1",
    "preact": "^8.2.5"
  }
}
```

It seems the pre and post install script on above example only works when I do `npm install`, but I want that to run every time I try to install anything.

For example: Let's say I want to write a script to check for the version of the package any time my team runs `npm install <some package>`. I want to check for the version of installing package and verify that it's version is above "1.0.0" else don't let them install.

I was planning to write a preinstall script that goes

`npm info lodash version`

and checks for the version of any package I am trying to install. If the version is not available, I plan to make it interactive and ask user's acknowledgement before install.

Comment: That's a cool idea, but npm doesn't have a hook for that.

Answer (score 13):

You are right the preinstall script runs only when we do npm install and there is currently no way to run a script before installing a module but you can use **shell scripting** and **npm view**
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view to do so .

First , create a moduleinstall.sh file which has the same scope as your package.json and the below shell script to it

```
echo 'Enter the name of the module'
read module_name
npm view $module_name version 
echo "Do you want to install this version(y/N) " 
read option 
if [ "$option" = "N" ] || [ "$option" = "n" ]
then 
echo "exiting...."
exit 1
else
npm install $module_name
fi
```

make sure you make it executable using `chmod +x moduleinstall.sh` and then write this in your package.json

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"info": "./moduleinstall.sh"
}
```

Now you just have to run the command `npm run info` and then follow the instruction to install a module by checking the version . You can advance it using different options of npm view and shell scripting. 
Hope this helps.