# npm postinstall runs only when not installing anything

Tags: reactjs, npm, post-install

## I was wrong

The reason why `npm install whatever` deletes the `node_modules/-` folder is different: I thought it runs `preinstall` but no `postinstall` and I was wrong.

I runs neither of the two scripts.

The reason seems to be that `npm install whatever` also *removes* all packages not mentioned in my `package.json`. Funnilly, it does not *install* packages mentioned in my `package.json` but missing in `node_modules`. It's exactly like Michael Waddell wrote in a comment. This makes no sense to me, but....

---

Following [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5118#issuecomment-434591873), I switched to absolute imports and rely on postinstall (in my own package.json) to create the link

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "rm node_modules/-",
    "postinstall": "ln -s `pwd`/src node_modules/-",
    ...
  },
}
```

It works well, unless when I really install something. With

```
npm install
```

the link gets deleted and then re-created. However, with

```
npm install whatever
```

the link gets deleted, but *not re-created*. Is this a bug or is this intentional and I should use some other "postinstall"?

*Please note that I'm not concerned about losing my `src` directory. That's a different problem. My problem is the "postinstall" running only sometimes.*

#### Update

People commented that the hooks only get run when running `npm install` without any arguments. I could live with that, but it's not true:

```
> ls -l node_modules/-
lrwxrwxrwx 1 maaartinus maaartinus 40 May 29 11:53 node_modules/- -> /home/maaartinus/work/octopus/reocto/src

> npm i whatever
foo bar baz blah

> ls -l node_modules/-
ls: cannot access 'node_modules/-': No such file or directory
```

This mean that `preinstall` runs, but `postinstall` did not. This sounds like a bug...

```
> node -v
v12.16.3
> npm -v
6.13.4
```

#### Update 2

The pre- and postinstall scripts are in *my own `package.json`* (which can be understood from the context, but I should have stated clearly).

Comment: I think you should check on this link for using absolute paths without getting any files deleted ..."   https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5118#issuecomment-464025389  " ...The link you mentioned it has some disadvantage as you can see in github.

Comment: @PALLAMOLLASAI I'm not afraid about this setting being dangerous - I know about the problem of cleaning the src directory via the symlink (a stupid old bug, hopefully solved in the meantime), but I commit very often, so the possible harm is limited. The problem with all the smart solutions is that none of them is supported by react/CRA. *They may break anytime.*

Comment: Could it be that postinstall is supposed to run when you install the current package, not when you install other packages?

Comment: @rayhatfield Maybe... I couldn't find any such info. Anyway, I need something really working...

Comment: @maaartinus Could you just [alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) your prefix in your webpack config? e.g. `{  '-': [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/')}`?

Comment: Sorry. I now see that that was the original question in the github issue you linked to. I guess you'd have to eject to change the webpack config, or change it locally in `node_modules/react-scripts/config/`, but the latter is a bit of a hack and it's going to reset every time you reinstall. You could have a postinstall script that updates the react-scripts config, but again, feels like a bit of a hack.

Comment: preinstall and postinstall scripts only run when you do an "npm install" - there's no way to run them when you install modules (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46729184/1238190).  It's not the case that the "preinstall" script is running but the "postinstall" is not.  Installing a module tells npm to "cleanup" the folder.  My recommendation would be to create a shell script (e.g. npm_install.sh) that does all 3 steps and use that instead of calling "npm install module"

Comment: As others have said, lifecycle hooks/scripts such as `postinstall` are invoked only when running the generic `npm install` command. However, If you're wanting a `postinstall` script to run whenever you run `npm install whatever` then you'll need to override npm's logic at the shell level. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59934610/run-a-script-like-postinstall-after-npm-installing-a-single-package/60096171#60096171) which shows how that can be achieved on _*nix_ when running `npm install whatever` in a specific project directory.

Comment: @MichaelWaddell I tried again, and it's not exactly true: See my edit.

Comment: @RobC Thank you, but what happens is pretty annoying, but doesn't deserve that much code - especially when it can't be placed in the directory itself. :(

Comment: @maaartinus - The behaviour demonstrated in your first **Update** section is a bug. When running `npm install whatever`, the `pre-` and `postinstall` scripts defined in your own _package.json_ should not be invoked. The expected behaviour is that they _should_ only be invoked when either; **A)** You run `npm install` in your projects directory. Or, **B)** Your resultant project/package is installed as a dependency for some other project. Interestingly, in [issue #481](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/481) someone is requesting the behaviour that you currently encounter as a new feature.

Comment: @MichaelWaddell You're right (and took me a while to understand it). Feel free to vote for closing as a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

sometime node currpted due to some reason therefore its delete node_module folder. you can install whatever by yarn

```
yarn add whatever
```

**[preinstall & postinstall](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)**

preinstall: Run BEFORE the package is installed install

postinstall: Run AFTER the package is installed.

**Absolute path:**

install [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) by

```
yarn add -D babel-plugin-module-resolver
yarn add -D customize-cra
```

then add relative path in `babel.config.js` file like this

```
const { override, addBabelPlugins } = require('customize-cra');
module.exports = override(

    ...addBabelPlugins([
        'module-resolver',
        {
            alias : {
                '@components'     : './src/components',
            }
        }
    ])
);
```

**then you can use an absolute path like this**

```
import TextLabel from '@components/textLabel/index.js'
```