# config 'npm i' to play audio during load time?

Tags: node.js, audio, playback

My instructor had a funny idea to play the 'Jeopardy' song when a user types 'npm i' into the terminal since it can sometimes take a few seconds to begin loading. I have what I think is the start of some code, but I have no idea on how to run this javascript file during a package download. Any ideas?

This plays the song

```
const Player = require('play-sound');
const player = new Player();

const jeopardy = './final-jeopardy.wav';

player.play(jeopardy, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error playing song:', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Enjoy the loading music!');
  }
});
```

This runs the postinstall to fetch the song from my machine. I tried to set the `npm config edit --global` to run this program, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const jeopardyScript = 'path/to/play/the/final/jeopardy/song.js';

console.log('Running final-jeopardy.js script');

const child = spawn('node', [jeopardyScript], { stdio: 'inherit' });

child.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log(`final-jeopardy.js script exited with code ${code}`)
  process.exit(code);
});
```

I have also published the package, which can be found using `npm i jeopardy-loading`

If anyone has any ideas or hints on how I can get this up and running would be awesome and a pleasant surprise for my instructor. Thanks!

I tried editing the `npm config edit --global` json to grab the postinstall.js file from my local machine.

I also tried editing my package.json, specifically the 'postinstall' to run the program after it is downloaded:

```
{
  "name": "jeopardy-loading",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Plays 'Final Jeopardy' song",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node final-jeopardy.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "jeopardy",
    "final-jeopardy",
    "audio"
  ],
  "author": "dsatpm",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "jeopardy-loading": "^1.0.0",
    "play-sound": "^1.1.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46556921/5156280

Comment: it's definitely closer than I was a few days ago. Thanks for the info!